# A replace for xmlrpc utility

Tags: xml, rtorrent, rpc

I’d wanted to use XMLRPC interface for rtorrent like described [here](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/wiki/RTorrentXMLRPCGuide), but xmlrpc from stable version of the xmlrpc-c package crashes and in unstable it is not present, so I searched for something that replaces it or how to do that with curl using that library, but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the configure option in xmlrpc-c to build the tools (which is simply OFF by default in newer versions), or use [rtxmlrpc](https://code.google.com/p/pyroscope/wiki/CommandLineTools#rtxmlrpc).